# Prevent Changes on GameObject from being saved

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I'm currently working on an Editor Script in Unity that disables specific GameObjects in a multi scene setup to make the Editor more responsive. I'm working with a setup that has up to 4 Scenes loaded at the same time. Since all these Scenes have many GameObjects in them (I'm talking thousands or even tens of thousands of Objects) the Unity Editor is getting pretty unresponsive and sloppy to use when these Scenes are loaded. Playing and Builds are fine btw, its only the Editor that is unusable.
So I'm working on a simple Editor Tool, that disables specific Parent Objects in all loaded Scenes so the Editor is usable again. This Tool works fine, but I want to prevent the changes on these GameObjects from being saved. I intentionally didn't mark the GameObjects as Dirty so Unity doesn't realize when I disable the Objects. Problem is, when I actually work on a Scene and save my work, the disabled GameObjects will be saved aswell, because at this point the Scene will be marked as Dirty. I've already looked into HideFlags but the problem there is, that I can't make Unity only ignore the changes that were made to an Object. HideFlags will only prevent the Object itself from being saved, which is not what I want.

If somebody knows a simple way to make Unity ignore changes on specific GameObjects that would be extremly helpful :)

Alternativly I would be interested in a way that enables me to run custom Code while Unity is saving the Scenes. That way I could make sure, that these GameObjects will be enabled, before Unity saves the Scene.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you increase your ram? It sounds like a ram problem to me. It would be a good investment anyway.

Comment: If you have that many objects .. you might want to re-think your project structure! What are these individual objects doing? Can you combine some of the functionalities? etc

Comment: @MehdiSabouri in specific for Unity the Editor scripts are quite complex and certain serialization operations can easily slow down the editor significantly no matter the RAM ... e.g. try to serialize and edit a list of strings in the Inspector that has 1000+ elements .. gets pretty slow already ;)

Comment: Ok. How about enabling your gameObject right before saving? Or maybe you can save your scene then manipulate the scene file to revert disabled gameObjects. Just an idea, I'm not sure if it works in your case. :)

Comment: @MehdiSabouri This problem definitly has nothing to do with RAM :) I'm even in worst case running at about 60% RAM usage with just 16 gb of RAM in the system :) Its just that Unitys Editor just isn't really designed to handle that many objects, even if the engine itself can handle them just fine :) But enabling the gameObjects before saving was what I was looking for with my alternitive solution. I just didn't know how to automate this to prevent user errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about preventing dirty objects from saving, doubt it is possible, but to run custom code before Unity saves a scene - easy.

Example editor script (remember it should be placed under `Editor/` dir to work as any other editor script)

```
using UnityEditor;

[InitializeOnLoad]
static class EditorSceneManagerSceneSaved {
    static EditorSceneManagerSceneSaved () {
        UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.sceneSaving += OnSceneSaving;
    }

    static void OnSceneSaving (UnityEngine.SceneManagement.Scene scene, string path) {
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogFormat ("Saving scene '{0}' to {1}", scene.name, path);
        /* Do your magic here */
    }
}
```

Credit for the example goes [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/editorscenemanager-scenesaved-example-no-code-examples-in-the-docs.488861/), more info on the API [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager-sceneSaving.html)